# Scapy import error 'socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, scapy, getaddrinfo

Im trying to install Scapy on windows 10, python 2.7.11, and stuck on this error:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\tools\python\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scapy.route import *
  File "C:\tools\python\lib\site-packages\scapy\route.py", line 182, in <module>
    _betteriface = conf.route.route("0.0.0.0", verbose=0)[0]
  File "C:\tools\python\lib\site-packages\scapy\route.py", line 150, in route
    aa = atol(a)
  File "C:\tools\python\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 400, in atol
    except socket.error:
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror), this error is thrown either by the getaddrinfo() or getnameinfo() function.
Judging by the stack trace, the scapy module tries to initialize a socket during its import and the port number is invalid (we can see the [atol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.atol) function being called, which convert a string to an integer).
It is unclear what the real issue is. However, you can try the following things:

- Make sure you have the right version of python and scapy. I suggest that you install scapy from pip, and maybe use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to run your script.
- You can also try to [compile scapy from source](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), or check the issue section in github to see if your problem is actually a known problem being worked on.
- Maybe scapy tries to initialize a raw socket (i don't know why they would, but its worth a try), which requires admin privileges. Try running your script as admin.

  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem is a simple indent error as it now split: '  File "C:\tools\python\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 399
    ip = inet_aton(x)
                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level' which is the code in the try section befor the code that filed. how can I compile a python file into a compiled python file myself?

Comment: A python library is actually just a python file (or multiple files). You don't need to compile anything, although it is feasible to pre-compile python source files.